# Pine script MVWAP strategy error: "cannot compile script"

Tags: compiler-errors, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Could someone kindly tell me where the error is in the following Pine script code?

MVWAP Strategy: Buy when the closing price is above MVWAP and sell when the closing price is below.

Thank you.

```
//@version=5
indicator("MVWAP Buy/Sell Strategy", shorttitle="MVWAP Strategy", overlay=true)

length = input(14, title="VWAP Length")

// Calculate VWAP
vwapValue = wma(close, length)

// Calculate MVWAP
mvwapValue = sma(vwapValue, length)

// Plot MVWAP on the chart
plot(mvwapValue, color=color.blue, title="MVWAP")

// Buy condition: Close is above MVWAP
buyCondition = close > mvwapValue

// Sell condition: Close is below MVWAP
sellCondition = close < mvwapValue

// Plot buy and sell signals on the chart
plotshape(series=buyCondition, title="Buy Signal", color=color.green, style=shape.labelup, text="Buy", location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(series=sellCondition, title="Sell Signal", color=color.red, style=shape.labeldown, text="Sell", location=location.abovebar)

// Strategy
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = buyCondition)
strategy.close("Buy", when = sellCondition)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
strategy("MVWAP Buy/Sell Strategy", shorttitle="MVWAP Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input(14, title="VWAP Length")
vwapValue = ta.wma(close, length)
mvwapValue = ta.sma(vwapValue, length)
plot(mvwapValue, color=color.blue, title="MVWAP")

buyCondition = close > mvwapValue
sellCondition = close < mvwapValue
plotshape(series=buyCondition, title="Buy Signal", color=color.green, style=shape.labelup, text="Buy", location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(series=sellCondition, title="Sell Signal", color=color.red, style=shape.labeldown, text="Sell", location=location.abovebar)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = buyCondition)
strategy.close("Buy", when = sellCondition)
```

The script you have provided contain several issues:

1. The type of script is `indicator()`, if you want to use the strategy functions and execute trades, you should use the `strategy()` type of script instead.
2. The declared version in the first line is version=5, however the built-in function calls do not include their namespaces (`ta.wma()` instead of just `wma()`), which is a requirement in v5.

Comment: If there is an answer to a question, mark it as accepted so others don't waste their time on it - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer